# Opencart Modification

Tags: php, opencart

I am currently using OpenCart 1.5. I need to display the product purchased in the orders page inside the admin: sales/order. along with the Order_id, customer, status, total, etc...

Should I be able to do this with a module? or can I modify the model (order.php) with another database query. Currently it is called getOrders($data = array()) but it only queries the .order_status database so therefore I can't return the product's name as part of the foreach results in the controller nor the view. Although line 562 in the same model looks pretty familiar to what I want but it is only used after an action is clicked on by the user.
Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two choices:

1. either You make Your edits using the vQmod XML file, while the original code stays intouched
2. or You make Your edits in the code directly (which may cause problems if You'd decide to upgrade in the future)

Anyway, a module won't do that (unless You think of vQmod edits as a module). You would need to edit the controller - `getList()` method and the model - `getOrders()` method. Think wisely how much information You want to display, as products may have other options and You may end up in a juggernaut query and only the list of 20 orders may take few seconds to complete...

Good luck.